# Add alternating count in select SQL Lite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a data like this.

[image]

it is ordered by Date and Person. Now my goal is to add a column and make it look like this.

[image]

as you can see based on sorting the starting row must be red. How can I achieve it in SQLLite?
here is my code so far dont how to combine it with the code that i want

`SELECT date,person FROM table_name
ORDER BY date,person`

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: im aware of that but i didnt include it because my code is only `SELECT` and i dont know whats next. anyways updated my post

Comment: Select date, person, color from table_name order by date, person;

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is not the best tool for this, but you can enumerate the rows using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.date = t.date and t2.person <= t.person
       ) as seqnum
from t;
```

Then you can use modulo arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then 'Red' else 'Blue' end) as color
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.date = t.date and t2.person <= t.person
             ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) 
order by date, seqnum;
```

Comment: its not working on me. when i add the `order by` the order shows with same color

Comment: @myownemail When I add `order by date, person` at the end, I get exactly your desired result.

Comment: where do i add the order by?

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.25.0 or later (which will not yet be available in Android in the near future), window functions are the simplest method to count rows in a group. Then use modulo-2 to check if the number is odd or even:

```
SELECT Date,
       Person,
       CASE row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Person) % 2
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Red'
         ELSE        'Blue'
       END AS Color
FROM table_name
ORDER BY Date, Person;
```

Comment: Well, do you have SQLite 3.25?

Comment: i am using the sql used in android studio